# cant install kivy in ubuntu

Tags: python, kivy

i have downloaded kivy as a .tar.gz file and i have extracted it by :

```
tar -zxvf kivy-1.9.1.tar.gz
```

when its extracted into a folder i try to install it by :

```
python setup.py install
```

but i get this error :

```
 In file included from kivy/graphics/opengl.c:242:0:
 kivy/graphics/gl_redirect.h:43:22: fatal error: GL/gl.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

and other errors(that are too much to mention here)
how can i solve the problem,if you know a better way to install kivy please mention it.

thank you

NOTE : i have the latest version of gcc

Comment: You seem to lag opengl dev files.. Most liekly you will need to install an additional packages you can find e.g. via packages.ubuntu.com

Comment: pip install kivy doesnt works either

Comment: You'll need something like `apt-get install opengl-dev` or something to that effect. And probably several other dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this [User Guide](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-linux.html) you can add one of the PPAs with this command:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kivy-team/kivy
```

Do an update:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Than you can install kivy:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-kivy
```

or in an alternative way based on [this page](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation.html), you can first install the dependencies:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-setuptools python-pygame python-opengl \
  python-gst0.10 python-enchant gstreamer0.10-plugins-good python-dev \
  build-essential libgl1-mesa-dev-lts-quantal libgles2-mesa-dev-lts-quantal\
  python-pip
```

than you can get the source code from github. and compile it via `$ python setup.py build_ext --inplace -f` or simply enter `make`